# List item images perfect on Chrome/Edge, css fudged on FF/IE

Tags: css

This is the website I'm developing: [www.finalverdict.be](http://finalverdict.be/). If you open an item, let's say [this one](http://finalverdict.be/overwatch/), and scroll down, you can see six related posts. The related posts' layout is looking good in Chrome/Edge, but way too wide on FF/IE.

This is the CSS:

```
.related-posts ul{
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.related-posts li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-position: outside;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 1px;
}

.related-post-a{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
}

.related-post-title{
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(46, 138, 250, 0.5);
}
```

What went wrong? I can't find a working solution, tried playing around with !important and more.

Comment: FWIW, they look the same for me in Chrome and FF (on a mac)

Comment: Hey! They do know, apparently FF/IE need an extra line of code to make sure the div only takes x percentage of its parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently FF/IE need an extra line of code to declare that a div only can take 100 % width of its parent. Sorry for answering this myself, kept searching and eventually found a working solution.